# Query to partially match every word in a search term in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an array of tags containing words.

```
tags: ['australianbrownsnake', 'venomoussnake', ...]
```

How do I match this against these search terms:
'brown snake', 'australian snake', 'venomous', 'venomous brown snake'

I am not even sure if this is possible since I am new to Elasticsearch. 
Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: I have created an ngram analyzer and added a field called ngram like so.

```
properties": {
    "tags": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
          "ngram": { 
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          }
        }
    }
```

i tried the following query but no luck

```
"query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "snake",
          "fields": [
            "tags.ngram"
          ],
          "type": "most_fields"
        }
      }
```

my tag mapping is as follows:

```
        "tags" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "ngram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
```

my settings are:

```
{
  "image" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "max_ngram_diff" : "10",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "image",
        "creation_date" : "1572590562106",
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "my_analyzer" : {
              "tokenizer" : "my_tokenizer"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer" : {
            "my_tokenizer" : {
              "token_chars" : [
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ],
              "min_gram" : "3",
              "type" : "ngram",
              "max_gram" : "10"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "pO9F7W43QxuZmI9vmXfKyw",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7040299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update:

This config should work fine.
I believe it was my mistake. I was searching on the wrong index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index your tags in the way you want to search them. For queries like 'brown snake', 'australian snake' to match your tags you would need to break them into smaller tokens.

By default elasticsearch indexes strings by passing it through its standard analyzer. You can always create your custom analyzer to store your field however you want. You can create your custom analyzer which tokenizes strings into nGrams. You can specify a size of 3-10 which will store your 'australianbrownsnake' tag as something like: ['aus', 'aust', ..., 'tra', 'tral',...]

You can then modify your search query to match on your `tags.ngram` field and you should get the desired results.
`tags.ngrams` field can be created like so:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

using ngram tokenizer:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

EDIT1: Elastic tends to use the analyzer of the field being matched on, to  analyze the query keywords. You might not need the user query to be tokenized in nGrams since there should be a matching nGram stored in the tags field. You could specify a standard `search_analyzer` in your mappings.

Comment: Ive already created a custom ngram analyzer and a tags.ngram field in the mapping. I am not sure how to do queries now

Comment: Could you also post the mappings of your index? Also, you need to reindex your data because you need elastic to re-analyze your `tags` field to store them in nGrams.

Comment: Okay sorry for not being clear enough. Please post the settings as well. Need to look at the definition of "my_analyzer".

Comment: I think it looks all fine. Try analyzing the text through your "my-analyzer" and see what it returns. Also, make sure you have reindexed the data into your index with the new mappings.
Use this GET API for analyzing: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html

Comment: I believe it was an error on my part. I was searching on the wrong index

Comment: Awesome. Hope i helped